# How to write these linq queries in the most optimal way

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, linq, optimization

I have a list that contains thousands of strings. I want to remove all of the strings that contains certain strings and also select distinct and min length 4. Currently below queries working very well however I believe performance is not the best. Can they be written to perform more efficiently?

C# 5 .net 4.5.2 wpf application

```
 List<string> lstFoundUrls = new List<string>{"filled with strings"};//lets say 1000

public static List<string> lstBannedUrlExtensions = new List<string> { ".png", ".jpg", ".gif", ".pdf", ".jpeg", ".txt", ".doc", ".docx", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".css", ".js", ".ico" };

lstFoundUrls = lstFoundUrls.Where(pr => lstBannedUrlExtensions.Where(ar => pr.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(ar) == true ).Count<string>() == 0).ToList<string>();

lstFoundUrls = lstFoundUrls.Where(pr => pr != "null").Where(pr => pr.Length > 4).Distinct<string>().ToList<string>();
```

Comment: Consider using [Any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Count()`. Also, why not combine the 2 queries?

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

Firstly, you are counting how many banned extensions each url contains. So if a url contains .png, you aren't stopping, and checking that url for .jpg, .gif etc.

Secondly, you're performing `ToLowerInvariant` on every string repeatedly, rather than just once per string. This means you're doing X * Y calls to `ToLowerInvariant` rather than just X.

Thirdly, you are throwing out all the strings that contain `"null"` and below minimum length after performing the costly checks. These checks should come first - throw away as many urls as possible as quickly as possible. (The "null" check is also redundant since you throw out any strings below length 5 anyway).

Fourthly, you are using `.Distinct()` rather than just using a `HashSet` to begin with.

Lastly, you are iterating over all file extensions for each url, rather than finding the file extension for each url and checking an O(1) collection (e.g. a `Hashset`) to see if the extension is banned.

Something like this would be better:

```
        var foundUrls = new HashSet<string>(lstFoundUrls);
        var bannedExtensions = new HashSet<string> { "png", "jpg", "gif", "pdf", "jpeg", "txt", "doc", "docx", "ppt", "pptx", "css", "js", "ico" };

        var filteredUrls = foundUrls.Where(s => s.Length > 4);
        var foundUrlsWithExtension = filteredUrls.ToDictionary(url => url, url => Path.GetExtension(url.ToLowerInvariant()));

        var filteredUrls2 = foundUrlsWithExtension.Where(kvp => !bannedExtensions.Contains(kvp.Value));
```